# Left Alignment in a list of questions with alignment of answers to the right

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, cv, alignment

I am trying to type up something like this in latex:

[image]

Here is my noobie attempt at something like it, I know this is probably horrible but I'm still very new. I just can't get the leading text (Name, DoB, Sex, Address etc.) to be flush left.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\section*{PERSONAL DETAILS}
\begin{flalign*}
\text{Name}                      &\quad \text{: Name}&\\
\text{Date of Birth}             &\quad \text{: Date}&\\
\text{Sex}                       &\quad \text{: Male}&\\
\text{Address}                   &\quad \text{: Address}&
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

But it outputs something like this instead of what I want:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I'd remove the colons.

Answer (score 1):

Use `tabular` for tables:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\section*{PERSONAL DETAILS}
\begin{tabular}{l l}%< the l aligns left
Name                      &: Name\\
Date of Birth             &: Date\\
Sex                       &: Male\\
Address                   &: Address
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe `\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}` for removing the outer paddings.

Comment: Also use a larger spacing than the default  between the two columns, and maybe a different font in each column (boldface,  italic or sans serif for the left column).