# Aligning the title page

Tags: horizontal-alignment, titles

I am trying to format my title page. Does anyone know how to align some rows by the middle so I get this result?

[image]

Comment: Welcome. The first line is shifted, is this intentional or  by accident? Please have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209993/how-to-customize-my-titlepage/210280#210280 and https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Title_Creation

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/413591/37907 but use `\begin{tabular}{r l}` instead.